# Saving multiple images in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to save in my db multiple images(max 5), how can I do that?
To save images I have this input:

```
?= $form->field($Form, 'images[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*','id'=>'gallery-photo-add'])->label(false) ?>
```

And in my Model I have field *images* and *fields for 5 images* that must to save;
But when I'm trying to get images like that:

```
$Form->image1 = $this->images[0];
```

This one is empty in my db.
Maybe problem is that massive saved in $_FILES?
What I have in my request:

```
$_FILES
Name    Value
Form    [
    'name' => [
        'images' => [
            0 => 'weight.png'
        ]
    ]
    'type' => [
        'images' => [
            0 => 'image/png'
        ]
    ]
    'tmp_name' => [
        'images' => [
            0 => 'W:\\XAMPP\\tmp\\php3FD3.tmp'
        ]
    ]
    'error' => [
        'images' => [
            0 => 0
        ]
    ]
    'size' => [
        'images' => [
            0 => 500
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save multiple images you should use Yii2's UploadedFile class.
   For example you want to save multiple images in your database. Your controller's code is something like:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            if ($model->upload()) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                return;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

This is model:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile[]
     */
    public $imageFiles;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) { 
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In your upload function you can save images to your db or save them in a folder and write image's path to the respective field in your table.

Comment: You can read documentation on UploadedFile here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html